# Cannot view files in default changelist

Tags: perforce

For some reason when I use p4 opened -c default or p4 opened, it says no files are in the default changelist. However, if I make a new changelist, move a file to it and use p4 opened -c CL_NUMBER, it will then show me the file in there. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `p4 opened` shows no opened files, the most likely explanation is that there are no files opened in your current client.

```
C:\Perforce\test\python>p4 opened
//stream/test/bar#1 - edit default change (text)

C:\Perforce\test\python>p4 opened -c default
//stream/test/bar#1 - edit default change (text)
```

Try running `p4 opened -a` to see all files opened on all clients, and run `p4 info` if you're not sure what your current client is.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I run p4 -c default -a, I can see the files now. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, that means they're opened on a different client.  On a server with many other users and clients, that command would show you *everyone's* opened files instead of just yours.

Comment: Are these files listed anywhere? I'm trying to create a system where I can "pre submit" files to a jenkins pipeline, and allow my team to compile code via this pre-submission feature before it goes into the mainline stream. I can see the file names in other pending changelists, but not in the default one for some reason.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question -- they're listed by `p4 opened -a`, correct?  (You can omit the `-c default` to just view every open file in every changelist.)

Comment: Yeah of course. I'm just curious how do I access these files on someone elses changelist. For example, I want people to be able to "presubmit" files before it's accepted to p4. I would run a script which grabs t heir changes and make sure it compiles before approving it.

Comment: If you want to do it during an actual submit, that's a `change-content` trigger.  If you want them to explicitly stage the files on the server before submitting, that's `p4 shelve`.  (You'll need to do some googling, but hopefully those give you the right phrases to search on!)

Comment: Is there no way to do a "build test" without submitting? Am I able to access the files directly from a pending changelist, and just do the compilication?

Comment: Yes, via `p4 shelve`.  Unless of course you have direct access to the client machine -- p4 itself does not grant the server a "backdoor" into client machines though.

Comment: I feel like there's another way without shelving. My friend who works at Activision told me they do this but it does not shelf the files, or put them into a separate stream...

Comment: I'd guess they have some kind of service running on the client machines that makes workspace content continuously available to whatever system does that.  Shelves are the standard way, though.  (That or your friend was unclear on the details of how this works -- I'd actually be quite surprised if there were a CI setup for files in Perforce that didn't involve either shelving or submitting files.)

Comment: Yeah I imagine shelving stuff would make more sense to me honestly. Doing some background service like that sounds like unnecessary work...

Comment: Although, I know that all the activision computers can be used (all employee pc's) are actually build agents for building the games they make, so maybe it's what you said.